# Get String from Text view content

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, text

In one of my generics views, I define a "Content" parameter as View to be passed, as I need to present on this generics view row content from a FetchRequest in Core Data. For a swipe actions of that ForEach, I need to get the string passed from that view:

```
struct MyView<Object: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {
  var items: FetchedResults<Object>
  var rowContent: (Object) -> Content
  
  init(items: FetchedResults<Object>, rowContent: @escaping (Object) -> Content) {
    self.items = items
    self.rowContent = rowContent
  }
  
  @State private var editingItemName = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        rowContent(item)
        
        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
           Button {
              editingItemName = rowContent(item)  
              //Here I can't get just string value. Just something like "Text(storage: SwiftUI.Text.Storage.verbatim("text_I_need_to_get"), modifiers: [])"
```

Which is called from another view with:

```
struct ParentView: View {
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var items: FetchedResults<MyEntity>

var body: some View {
    Form {
      NavigationLink(destination: MyView(items: instruments, rowContent: { item in
          Text(item.name ?? "")
          })) {
            Label("Items", systemImage: "star")
          }
          //More code here
```

rowContent(item) inside the ForEach works perfectly, but how could I grab just the string "text_I_need_to_get"?

Comment: You can't, SwiftUI wrappers are "hidden" in a secret storage for a number of reasons (Watch Demystify SwiftUI), you have use `item` or make the source of truth for the value you need at the same level with the `Button`

Comment: Thanks. When using `editingItemName = item`it throws an error: "Cannot assign value of type 'FetchedResults<Object>.Element' (aka 'Object') to type 'String'". Could you clarify a little more "make the source of truth for the value at the same level with the Button", please?

Comment: The error is clear "MyEntity" is not a `String` and vice versa but you like want to make an additional subview where you can use `@ObservedObject` for `item`